# ¿Por qué el compilador no reconoce las propiedades de mi clase en Blazor/C# a pesar de estar definidas correctamente?

Tags: mysql, c#, blazor

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación tipo Blazor con C# y MySQL, pero estoy enfrentando un problema al construir una página. A continuación, detallo los errores que estoy obteniendo:

```
@page "/PlanDesaMineralEstrella"
@inject PlanDesaMineralEstrellaServicio PlanDesaMineralEstrellaServicio
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<h3>PlanDesaMineralEstrella</h3>

<NavLink class="btn btn-primary" href="/PlanDesaMineralEstrella/Add">Agregar PlanDesaMineralEstrella</NavLink>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Estructura</th>
            <th>Zona</th>
            <th>Labor</th>
            <th>Tipo Labor</th>
            <th>Ancho</th>
            <th>Total Ancho</th>
            <th>Alto</th>
            <th>Total Alto</th>
            <th>Longitud</th>
            <th>Total Longitud</th>
            <th>M3</th>
            <th>Total M3</th>
            <th>Tons</th>
            <th>Total Tons</th>
            <th>Costo</th>
            <th>Empresa</th>
            <th>Equipo</th>
            <th>Agregar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in PlanDesaMineralEstrellas)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.IdDesMinEst</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "IdDesMinEst" ni un método de extensión accesible "IdDesMinEst" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.Fecha.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "Fecha" ni un método de extensión accesible "Fecha" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.Estructura</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "Estructura" ni un método de extensión accesible "Estructura" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.Zona</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "Zona" ni un método de extensión accesible "Zona" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.Labor</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "Labor" ni un método de extensión accesible "Labor" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.TipoLabor</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "TipoLabor" ni un método de extensión accesible "TipoLabor" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.Ancho</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "Ancho" ni un método de extensión accesible "Ancho" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.TotalAncho</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "TotalAncho" ni un método de extensión accesible "TotalAncho" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.Alto</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "Alto" ni un método de extensión accesible "Alto" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.TotalAlto</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "TotalAlto" ni un método de extensión accesible "TotalAlto" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.Longitud</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "Longitud" ni un método de extensión accesible "Longitud" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.TotalLongitud</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "TotalLongitud" ni un método de extensión accesible "TotalLongitud" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.M3</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "M3" ni un método de extensión accesible "M3" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.TotalM3</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "TotalM3" ni un método de extensión accesible "TotalM3" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.Tons</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "Tons" ni un método de extensión accesible "Tons" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.TotalTons</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "TotalTons" ni un método de extensión accesible "TotalTons" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.Costo</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "Costo" ni un método de extensión accesible "Costo" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.Empresa</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "Empresa" ni un método de extensión accesible "Empresa" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>@item.Equipo</td> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "Equipo" ni un método de extensión accesible "Equipo" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(() => BorrarPlanDesaMineralEstrella(item.IdDesMinEst))">Borrar</button> //"PlanDesaMineralEstrella" no contiene una definición para "IdDesMinEst" ni un método de extensión accesible "IdDesMinEst" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "PlanDesaMineralEstrella" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    List<PlanDesaMineralEstrella> PlanDesaMineralEstrellas;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        PlanDesaMineralEstrellas = await PlanDesaMineralEstrellaServicio.ObtenerTodo();
    }

    private async Task BorrarPlanDesaMineralEstrella(int id)
    {
        var confirmar = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "¿Estás seguro de que quieres borrar este registro?"); //"List<PlanDesaMineralEstrella>" no contiene una definición para "GetAwaiter" ni un método de extensión accesible "GetAwaiter" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "List<PlanDesaMineralEstrella>" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
        if (confirmar)
        {
            var resultado = await PlanDesaMineralEstrellaServicio.Borrar(id); //"bool" no contiene una definición para "GetAwaiter" ni un método de extensión accesible "GetAwaiter" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "bool" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
            if (resultado)
            {
                PlanDesaMineralEstrellas = await PlanDesaMineralEstrellaServicio.ObtenerTodo(); //"List<PlanDesaMineralEstrella>" no contiene una definición para "GetAwaiter" ni un método de extensión accesible "GetAwaiter" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "List<PlanDesaMineralEstrella>" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)CS1061
            }
            else
            {
                // Manejo de errores o mensajes de alerta si falla el borrado
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El problema radica en que, a pesar de que tengo la clase PlanDesaMineralEstrella con todas las propiedades requeridas, el compilador indica que no existen tales propiedades o métodos en la clase. Adjunto la definición de la clase:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class PlanDesaMineralEstrella
{
    public int IdDesMinEst { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateOnly Fecha { get; set; }

    public string Estructura { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Zona { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Labor { get; set; } = null!;

    public string TipoLabor { get; set; } = null!;

    public float Ancho { get; set; }

    public float TotalAncho { get; set; }

    public float Alto { get; set; }

    public float TotalAlto { get; set; }

    public int Longitud { get; set; }

    public int TotalLongitud { get; set; }

    public int M3 { get; set; }

    public int TotalM3 { get; set; }

    public int Tons { get; set; }

    public int TotalTons { get; set; }

    public string Costo { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Empresa { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Equipo { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Incluso he validado que las propiedades sean públicas y que los nombres coincidan, pero sigo recibiendo los errores. Además, adjunto el servicio PlanDesaMineralEstrellaServicio que maneja las operaciones con la base de datos.

```
public class PlanDesaMineralEstrellaServicio {
    private readonly ContextoDatos ctx;
    public PlanDesaMineralEstrellaServicio(ContextoDatos contexto) => ctx = contexto;
    public List<PlanDesaMineralEstrella> ObtenerTodo() {
        return ctx.PlanDesaMineralEstrellas.ToList();
    }

    public bool AgregarActualizar(PlanDesaMineralEstrella plandesamineralestrella) {
        try {
            if (plandesamineralestrella.IdDesMinEst == 0) ctx.PlanDesaMineralEstrellas.Add(plandesamineralestrella);
            else ctx.PlanDesaMineralEstrellas.Update(plandesamineralestrella);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return false; }
    }

    public PlanDesaMineralEstrella EcontrarPorId(int Id) {
        return ctx.PlanDesaMineralEstrellas.Find(Id);
    }

    public bool Borrar(int id) {
        try {
            var plandesamineralestrella = EcontrarPorId(id);
            if(plandesamineralestrella==null) 
                return false;
            else ctx.PlanDesaMineralEstrellas.Remove(plandesamineralestrella);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) { return false; }
    }
}
```

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia o ayuda para resolver este problema. ¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Puedes que tengas 2 clases con el mismo nombre `PlanDesaMineralEstrella`